# *** -[UIDeviceRGBColor size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x25f110

Tags: iphone

```
-[UIDeviceRGBColor size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x31e520
2010-03-18 12:36:48.511 IChitMe[4012:207] Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '** -[UIDeviceRGBColor size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x31e520'
```

I'm getting this exception when I'm clicking on back button of `UIToolBar`.

Comment: Could you provide the code that generates this error?

Comment: I'm also getting crash reports of this. Did you find a fix?

Comment: Actually, mine is crashing with [UIDeviceRGBColor superView], but this is totally system code as it's not in any of my code at all.

Answer (score 1):

[UIDeviceRGBColor size] selector is NOT defined for the object you are calling it on.

Comment: means?i don't understand
can u give me example?

Comment: e.g. This won't work - [NSString makeMeASandwich]; because NSString doesn't have the makeMeASandwich method. Edit your question and add the line of code that's causing this error and we might be able to help you more :)